# Paginación en laravel, cómo logralo

Tags: html, laravel, blade

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($actividades as $actividad)
  <tr id="{{ $actividad['pkActividad'] }}">
    <td>{{ $actividad['nomProveedor'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $actividad['nomActividad'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $actividad['creadoPor'] }}</td>
    @if($actividad['esActivo'] == 2)
    <td class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-primary">Activo</span></td>
    @elseif($actividad['esActivo']== 1)
    <td class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-warning">Pendiente</span></td>
    @else
    <td class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Rechazado</span></td>
    @endif
    <td><a href="" id="btnAprobar" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">Aprobar</a></td>
    <td><a href="" id="btnRechazar" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger delete-user">Rechazar</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="preview" class="btn btn-outline btn-warning">Vista Previa</a></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Quiero hacer una paginación de esta tabla, los datos son obtenidos en un objeto a través de una api, hay alguna forma de hacer esto posible? en la tabla se muestran 15 registros si hay más se muestran en la siguiente pagina de la tabla.
agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Ya leiste la documentacion de laravel?

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z obviamente, usaría el método que ahí describen pero como no es una consulta directa no funciona

Comment: [Manually Creating A Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) ([constructor](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php#L32))

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaria usar el pagineo de DataTable, con este puedes filtrar si quieres que las paginas tengan 10,25,50,100 registros por pagina y aparte tiene búsqueda masiva todo esto obviamente comunicándose con el servidor.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side